# How to make left/right image/text layout responsive as an above/below layout?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've got a features/benefits block in my site that, at desktop-type widths, is set up in that image left / text right; text left / image right type of structure.

image words

words image

image words

You can see that here -- http://jsfiddle.net/thjz3qp9/

However, when screen sizes get down to round about smartphone landscape and below, I want that section to collapse to an image above the words layout.

image

words

image

words

The structure of the html makes that difficult:

```
<div class="benefits-block">
    <div class="left>
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p> ... </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="benefits-block">
    <div class="left>
        <p> ... </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

-- creating a scenario of:

image

words

words

image

-- at smaller resolutions. That can be seen at the same fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/thjz3qp9/ if you click 'Settings' > 'Bottom results' and resize your browser to that breakpoint (or if you have a look on a phone).

How can I have that left/right benefits type of structure at larger resolutions but have it collapse to an image above text structure at smaller resolutions when the html is essentially `<img> <p> <p> <img>`?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand the issue. You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/thjz3qp9/1/  ?

Comment: That's really helpful @AlonEitan -- I also figured out another fix at the same moment, but that's very elegant too. Thanks.

Comment: NP, please delete this post if you figured it out. You can also post an answer (self-answer you question), but don't just edit the post like you did

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0):

Since logically the order should be image first, then words (as in the mobile design), that's how you want to have it in your HTML. Then, use CSS to position the blocks how you want.

Rather than targeting the container div (`.benefits-left`), try targeting the image inside it: `.benefits-left img`. That way, you can tell it to float left or right depending on the container class without rearranging the HTML.